# Python replace multiple e-mail headers/payloads

Tags: python, email, replace, email-headers, payload

I'm writing a Python script that is parsing the e-mail message and iterate over it's headers and payloads. I need to replace there each mention of ABC to XYZ (basic string replacement), However I need to do that for fields in headers as well as text of payload (text/plain or text/html). According to the docs, there is replace_header function which will replace only the first header with that name and thus fail for example for "Received" headers.

For the message payloads, I need something like walk() method where I can use search/replace which will propagate the changes when I export the censored e-mail back into it's RAW form (eml).

Could you give me som tips about how to do it without constructing a copy of the e-mail (e.g. to do it in-place) with the censored informations? Thanks!

Sidenote: search & replace in RAW form doesn't work as that often breaks format and largely depends on used encoding (for example exchange breaks line after 78 chars with =\r\n)

Comment: Please provide the code you got so far and some (anonymised) sample snippets of your mails.

Comment: I'm afraid that might not be possible as it is a part of the high-security system. However here are some information that I can disclose: Let's say, that I work for "company.com", I need to replace each mention of it in the message headers to XXX (mainly "Received" headers) to prevent exposure of internal system structure and servers. I then need to censor employee names/IDs and so on the message body (and headers). This censored e-mail is than sent to the microsoft exchange team to tune their filters (mostly just spam filters) hence I need to keep as much of the original structure.